# Python Regex: Find patterns without repetitions

Tags: python, regex

I want to find patterns in string as follows,

```
a = "3. ablkdna 08. 15. adbvnksd 4."
```

The expected patterns are like below,

```
match = "3. "
match = "4. "
```

I want to exclude the patterns,

```
([0-9]+\.[\s]*){2,}
```

But only find the patterns of length 1. not `08.` and `15.`.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will work for given two examples:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<!\d\.\s)(?<!\d)\d+\.(?!\s*\d+\.)')
a = "3. ablkdna 08. 15. adbvnksd 4."
m = re.findall(p, a)
print(m)
# prints  ['3.', '4.']

a = "3. (abc), adfb 8. 1. adfg 4. asdfasd"
m = re.findall(p, a)
print(m)
# prints  ['3.', '4.']
```

Apparently the regex above is *not* complete and there are
many exceptions to allow "false-positive".

In order to write a complete regex which excludes an arbitrary pattern,
we will need to implement the **absent operator** `(?~exp)` which was
introduced in Ruby 2.4.1 and not available in Python as of now.

As an alternative, how about a two step solution:

```
m = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s*', re.sub(r'(\d+\.\s*){2,}', '', a))
```

which may not be elegant.